# Adding headers in postfix incoming mails

Tags: header, postfix-mta

I am unable to see the following headers in e-mails received on my Postfix e-mail receiving server:

1. Return-Path
2. Received: from 
   Similar to header on gmail 
   Received: from dev16 ([123.123.123.123])
       by mx.google.com with SMTP id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
       Tue, 27 Oct 2009 05:52:56 -0700 (PDT)
3. Return-To:

Please suggest me what should I do to add these headers in the received e-mails.

Thanks in advance.

Ashish

Comment: This should go to server fault or even superuser, I'd have thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the e-mail contains these headers, but the mail viewer client needs to be configured to show these headers.

Actually i needed to parse the email headers for anti spoofing, and i was unable to see these headers with the mail client i was using therefore i thought these headers are not present.

But once i checked the actual mbox file and cleared all my doubts.

Also for appending custom headers in Postfix received e-mail one can use milter protocol implemented in Postfix by using 'lib-milter' provided by sendmail.

For java implementation one can use 'jilter'.